# Resolve Upload Insert Failed merge conflict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, merge-replication

I have a series of rows created at the Subscriber that are not being replicated to the Publisher. The conflict viewer shows a Conflict Type of `5(Upload insert failed)` with this error:

> A row insert at '{subscriber}' could not be propagated to '{Publisher}'. This failure can be caused by a constraint violation.  The merge process was unable to synchronize the row.

If I click "Submit Loser" to resolve it, I get this error:

> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint in database '{Database}', replicated table '{Table}', column '{Column}'. If the identity column is automatically managed by replication, update the range as follows: for the Publisher, execute sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.
>   The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 548)

I have run `sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange` and any new rows created are being replicated successfully, but these ones still won't replicate. It's important to keep the row Id's that were created on the subscriber, so I can't remove and re-insert the row. How can I resolve these conflicts?

Comment: It will be hard to tell post mortem what has caused this.  For one of the conflicts in question, try temporarily disabling the identity range check constraint, then try submitting the loser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue wasn't actually caused by the identity column of table A, it was a foreign key column. The row in table B that the rows in table A FK'd to did not replicate either. I don't yet know why those row didn't replicate.

I triggered replication by updating a value in each row of table B which caused replication to see a change and replicate those. After those were replicated, each row in table A replicated correctly and everything is in sync again.